# PyQGIS error: proj_create_from_database: Cannot find proj.db

Tags: python, pyqgis, api

I have problem with QGIS. When I run my code in QGIS Python console it works but when I try in console I'm getting an error. Code:

```
import sys
 
from qgis.core import QgsApplication, QgsProcessingFeedback
from qgis.analysis import QgsNativeAlgorithms
 
QgsApplication.setPrefixPath(r'C:/PROGRA~1/QGIS3~1.16/apps/qgis', True)
qgs = QgsApplication([], True)
qgs.initQgis()
 
# Add the path to processing so we can import it next
sys.path.append(r'C:/PROGRA~1/QGIS3~1.16/apps/qgis/python/plugins')

import processing
from processing.core.Processing import Processing
 
Processing.initialize()
QgsApplication.processingRegistry().addProvider(QgsNativeAlgorithms())
feedback = QgsProcessingFeedback()

processing.run("native:joinattributesbylocation", {'INPUT':'C:/Users/ja/Inne/Desktop/bdot10k_bubd_a/bdot10k_bubd_a.gpkg','JOIN':'C:\\Users\\ja\\Inne\\Desktop\\POLSKA\\PRG_PunktyAdresowe_POLSKA.shp','PREDICATE':[1,5],'JOIN_FIELDS':['PNA','SIMC_id','SIMC_nazwa','ULIC_nazwa','Numer'],'METHOD':1,'DISCARD_NONMATCHING':True,'PREFIX':'','OUTPUT':'C:/Users/ja/Inne/Desktop/projekt2.gpkg'})
```

What is the problem?

```
Error: >>>
... from qgis.core import QgsApplication, QgsProcessingFeedback
>>> from qgis.analysis import QgsNativeAlgorithms
>>>
... QgsApplication.setPrefixPath(r'C:/PROGRA~1/QGIS3~1.16/apps/qgis', True)
>>> qgs = QgsApplication([], True)
>>> qgs.initQgis()
>>>
... # Add the path to processing so we can import it next
... sys.path.append(r'C:/PROGRA~1/QGIS3~1.16/apps/qgis/python/plugins')
>>>
>>> import processing
>>> from processing.core.Processing import Processing
>>>
... Processing.initialize()
>>> QgsApplication.processingRegistry().addProvider(QgsNativeAlgorithms())
proj_create_from_database: Cannot find proj.db
True
>>> feedback = QgsProcessingFeedback()
>>>
>>> processing.run("native:joinattributesbylocation", {'INPUT':'C:/Users/ja/Inne/Desktop/bdot10k_bubd_a/bdot10k_bubd_a.gpkg','JOIN':'C:\\Users\\ja\\Inne\\Desktop\\POLSKA\\PRG_PunktyAdresowe_POLSKA.shp','PREDICATE':[1,5],'JOIN_FIELDS':['PNA','SIMC_id','SIMC_nazwa','ULIC_nazwa','Numer'],'METHOD':1,'DISCARD_NONMATCHING':True,'PREFIX':'','OUTPUT':'C:/Users/ja/Inne/Desktop/projekt2.gpkg'})
proj_create_from_wkt: Cannot find proj.db
proj_create_from_database: Cannot find proj.db
ERROR 1: PROJ: proj_identify: Cannot find proj.db
proj_create_from_wkt: Cannot find proj.db
proj_identify: Cannot find proj.db
proj_get_authorities_from_database: Cannot find proj.db
ERROR 1: PROJ: proj_identify: Cannot find proj.db
```

Comment: It looks like a problem with your %PATH% (on Windows) Try setting your GDAL environment variables PROJ_LIB and GEOTIFF_CSV - be sure that you set your paths to the correct bitedness for your python and QGIS - either all 32 bit or all 64 bit. Have a read of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14444310/how-to-set-the-gdal-data-environment-variable-to-point-to-the-directory-containi and add your GDAL folder to the end of your %PATH% or Windows doesn't know to look there for the bits it's trying to find.

Comment: did not work for me :/

Comment: This is a common problem https://gis.stackexchange.com/search?q=proj.db with GDAL versions >3.0 which are using Proj versions >6. Setting PROJ_LIB correctly is the way to make it work.

Comment: What means seeting PROJ_LIB correctly? I have PROJ_LIB - C:\Program Files\QGIS 3.16\share\proj\proj.db

Comment: It means to tell python that path to PROJ_LIB is `C:\Program Files\QGIS 3.16\share\proj`. I am not Python expert but setting a global environmental variable for your computer could work `SET PROJ_LIB="C:\Program Files\QGIS 3.16\share\proj"`

Comment: didnt work form me ;/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution:

I have changed interpreter and it works.

Interpreter:
C:\Program Files\QGIS 3.16\bin\python-qgis.bat